# Where should this final line go in this Python 3 for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting combine a bunch of CSVs into one file. I'm looping through all the files, keeping the header in the first file and skipping the header in all the rest. I either get an error with this code or I only get one file that has been doubled somehow. It all has to do with here I put:

```
final_result.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_trip_data.csv'), index=False)
```

If I put it in the else statement, I only get one file. If I try to put it anywhere else I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final_result' referenced before assignment
```

Below is an updated version but this seems to eat a ton of memory and I think it's writing the file more than once.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file_masks = ['fhv', 'green', 'yellow']


def combine_files(file_mask):

    for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.startswith(file_mask):
                combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveData/',f)) for f in files])
                if combined_csv.empty == False:
                    combined_csv.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_tripdata_combined.csv'), index=False)

for m in file_masks:
    combine_files(m)
```

Comment: Should `count = 2` be `file_count=2`

Comment: That helped but still getting the error about referenced before assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code is such that the `final_result` is only defined in the if block. So if the if block is skipped the else cannot execute as you have not defined `final_result` anywhere. You should also put the write csv statements outside the loop if you want all the combined csv files inside `'TaxiDriveData/'` to be put inside the file `'TaxiDriveCombinedData`. Your function should look like:

```
def combine_files(file_mask):
    file_count = 1
    for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.startswith(file_mask):
                if file_count == 1:
                    final_result = pd.read_csv('TaxiDriveData/' + fn)
                    file_count =+ 1
                else:
                    another_file = pd.read_csv('TaxiDriveData/' + fn, skiprows=1)
                    final_result.append(another_file)
   final_result.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_trip_data.csv'), index=False)
```

With `pandas` you also do not really need that much checking if all the csv contains same number of columns and the same header line. You can use the code below for function `combine_files()`

```
def combine_files(file_mask):
    csvfiles = []
    for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        csvfiles.extend([os.path.join(path,fn) for fn in files if fn.startswith(file_mask)])

    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(fn) for fn in csvfiles))
    df.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_trip_data.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: I think I was writing this solution at the same time you were. Mine is pretty close to yours but it is eating a TON of RAM. The final file might be bigger than the amount of ram on my machine. I was getting ready to switch to a method where I wrote the file and then appended to a written file if that is even possible.

Comment: I finally had a chance to check your answer against data. It only works with small amounts. The files I'm combing wind up being GBs and this process while it looks efficient actually freezes my computer.